# Why Lightsail bitnami after LetsEncrypy change index.html location

Tags: apache, lets-encrypt, bitnami, certbot

My Node.Js Bitnami Lightsail instance had its frontend code at `/opt/apache/htdocs` and http://example.com was working perfectly pointing to that directory (my backend located under `opt/projects`).

After executing Certbot LetsEncrypt my domain is now pointing to a different folder `/var/www/html`
Please advise on:

- In certbot instruction page I choose `Apache` for "My HTTP website is running", there wasn't a Bitnami option, was that the right call?
- Is this the right configuration and just move my code to html folder?
- Does my backend code has to move too? if so where?
- Any other well-known issues that I might face?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Bitnami Engineer here,

We do not have any guide to configure certbot and Bitnami, but we have a guide that helps you configure the Let's Encrypt SSL certificate using lego. We have a tool that configures everything so you do not need to worry about editing the Apache's conf files or setting the renew process.

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/bncert-tool
```

You can learn more about it [here](https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/how-to/understand-bncert/).

In case you want to manually create a SSL certificate, you can also run the lego tool directly

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/letsencrypt/lego --tls --email="EMAIL-ADDRESS" --domains="DOMAIN" --domains="www.DOMAIN" --path="/opt/bitnami/letsencrypt" run
```

You will later need to configure the Apache's conf files to use that new certificate file. You can learn more about it [here](https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/how-to/generate-install-lets-encrypt-ssl/#alternative-approach)

> Note: If you used certbot and it modified the Apache's configuration, you will need to undo those changes to use the proper folder. You will need to review the /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/httpd.conf, /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami.conf and /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/vhosts/* files